# Primefaces validation message

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How can I display custom validation message in using prime faces message tag?

My code:

```html
<p:messages id="message" />
<p:inputText id="updatedescription"
             value="#{equipTemplateBean.equipmentSpecificationsVO.description}"
             requiredMessage="Please enter Description"                                           
             required="true"/>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. For example where do you post the form and where do you update the messages component?

Comment: Add `globalOnly="false" like `<p:messages id="message" globalOnly="false"/>`